# Safari: make google highlighted search term open in another tab

Tags: safari

Safari (on mac anyways) only opens a google result of highlighted text in the same tab:

- select some text
- right click
- select "google" the highlighted text

Is it possible to get the results to open in a new tab? Can't seem to find a setting for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From that dropdown menu you've mentioned, click on "Search with Google" with the **middle mouse button**, or button 3. Optionally, use **CMD+click**.